# Replacement of nested ifelse using purrr & modify_if

Tags: r, loops, nested, purrr

This a mwe of what I'm trying to achieve, for some reason think using purrr and "modify_if" will be more efficient? In the application, it will grow rapidly so speed/efficiency is important.  This looks simple but what I need to do, will require several commands at each ifelse level.

```
vec1 <- c(1,2,3)
vec1 <- sapply(
  vec1,function(x) ifelse(x == 1,2,
                          ifelse (x == 2,3,
                                  ifelse (x == 3,1,0))))
vec1 #output
[1] 2 3 1
```

Also, how can I code an `ifelse`,if there is no else, i.e. if the predicate is not met I just want to do nothing?  Just use an `if` statement rather than `ifelse`.

Thx, J

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `sapply` here, `ifelse` is vectorized you can directly use it.

As an alternative you can use `dplyr::recode`.

```
dplyr::recode(vec1, `1` = 2, `2` = 3, `3` = 1)
#[1] 2 3 1
```

Or `case_when` which is an alternative to nested `ifelse` statements.

```
dplyr::case_when(vec1 == 1 ~2, vec1 == 2 ~3,  vec1 == 3 ~1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use a named vector in `base R` without using any packages or ifelse

```
unname(setNames(1:3, c(2, 3, 1))[as.character(vec1)])
```